# Unable to make custom validation method work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've added the following piece of code as a custom validation method for my model:

```
validate :delivery_date_cannot_be_after_order_date, on: :update

def delivery_date_cannot_be_after_order_date
    puts 'running method'
    if promised_delivery_date.present? && promised_delivery_date < self.created_at 
        puts 'detected error'
        errors.add(:promised_delivery_date, "can't be in the past")
    end
end
```

It never seems to pass the IF statement when I run this.

Later, I removed the IF statement, it still doesn't return any errors and update runs successfully.

I also tried this :

```
def delivery_date_cannot_be_after_order_date
    puts 'running method'
    if self.promised_delivery_date.present? && self.promised_delivery_date < self.created_at 
        puts 'detected error'
        errors.add(:promised_delivery_date, "can't be in the past")
    end
end
```

But still the same issue..

Here's the code when I ran it without the IF statement, I would assume that this would return an error everytime I update, but that didn't happen

Comment: you specified `on: :create` so validation will not run on update

Comment: Hi Oleg, I'm sorry I copied code from one of my tests, even `on: :update` didn't work :/

Comment: What `errors` method returns after you update the record? And do I understand correctly that `delivery_date_cannot_be_after_order_date` actually gets called (you see "running method" in a console)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to parse the date you have in your database like this: (I got something similar and worked with code as below)

```
def delivery_date_cannot_be_after_order_date
  puts 'running method'
  if promised_delivery_date.to_date.present? && promised_delivery_date.to_date < created_at.to_date
    puts 'detected error'
    errors.add(:promised_delivery_date, "can't be in the past")
  end
end
```

The thing here is that when you compare dates with < > = and those dates are casted into strings (somehow) those comparators will work only for the days and not months or years. So try parsing to an object `date` before you compare two dates.

See that the usage of `self` keyword is only necessary when you create class methods (called by the model anywhere), but in this case (I think) you need an instance method (called by any instance).

Comment: Apologies for the delayed reply, we had a natural disaster in Chennai. So I tried this, and got the error `Date with ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone failed`, so I used `promised_delivery_date.to_date` and it worked.

Comment: No need to apologize. I hope you are ok.